# Clearmake rules for handling stamp file and siblings from a large monolith command?

Tags: clearcase

Given a build process like this:

1. Run a VerySlowProcess that produces one output file for each given input file.
2. Run a SecondProcess on each output file from VerySlowProcess

VerySlowProcess is slow to start, but can handle additional input files without much extra delay, therefore it is invoked with several input files. VerySlowProcess may access additional files referenced from the input files, but we can not match the file accesses to specific input files, and therefore all derived output files from VerySlowProcess will get the same Configuration Record by clearmake.

Since VerySlowProcess is invoked with several input files (inlcuding input files that has not changed) many of the output files are overwritten again with identical content. In those cases it would be uneccesery to execute SecondProcess on them and therefore output is written to a temporary file, that is only copied to the real file if the content has actually changed.

Example Makefile:

```
all: a.3 b.3

2.stamp:
    @(echo VerySlowProcess simulated by two cp commands)
    @(cp a.1 a.2_tmp)
    @(cp b.1 b.2_tmp)
    @(diff -q a.2_tmp a.2 || (echo created new a.2; cp a.2_tmp a.2))
    @(diff -q b.2_tmp b.2 || (echo created new b.2; cp b.2_tmp b.2))
    @(touch $@)

%.3: %.2 2.stamp
    @(echo Simulating SecondProcess creating $@)
    @(cp $< $@)
```

If only a.1 is changed only a.2 is written, but SecondProcess is still executed also for b:

```
 > clearmake all
VerySlowProcess simulated by two cp commands
Files a.2_tmp and a.2 differ
created new a.2
Simulating SecondProcess creating a.3
Simulating SecondProcess creating b.3
```

As a workaround we can remove the '2.stamp' from the '%.3' dependencies, then it work to execute like this:

```
> clearmake 2.stamp && clearmake all
VerySlowProcess simulated by two cp commands
Files a.2_tmp and a.2 differ
created new a.2
Simulating SecondProcess creating a.3
```

Is there a better way to handle our problem with VerySlowProcess?

Comment: A potential problem with our workaround is that two sequential invokations of clearmake, makes it harder to get efficient parallellization of the build.

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround seems valid.
The only other use of clearmake for supporting "incremental update" is [presented here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21126251), but I am not sure if it applies in your case.

> Incremental updating means that a compound object, such as a library is partially updated by the rebuild of one or more of its components, as opposed to being generated by the build of just one target.
>
> The use of the `.INCREMENTAL_TARGET` is of importance here.
> This special target tells `clearmake` to merge the entries of the target's previous configuration record with those of the latest build.
> This way the build history of the object is not lost, because the object's configuration record is not completely overwritten every time the object gets modified.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I tried adding: '.INCREMENTAL_TARGET: 2.stamp' but as far as I can see, the behaviour did not change and b.3 is still always re-created.

Comment: @Ulrik: it was worth trying. I am not familiar enough with `clearmake` to propose a more precise solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alterative scenario though similar problem...perhaps...though your description does not quite match my scenario.

I have a very slow process that may change certain files but will regenerate all the files.
I want to avoid the slow process and also want to avoid updating the files that do not change.

```
Checked if regeneration (slow process) is necessary - this logic needed to be separated out from the makefile into a shell script since there are issues with clearmake with targets being updated and .INCREMENTAL could not help resolve.

Logic Overview:
  If the md5sums.txt file is empty or the md5sums do not match 
  then long process if invoked.

       To check md5sums:
           md5sum -c md5sums.txt
       To build slow target:
           clearmake {slowTarget}
           this will generate to a temp dir and afterwards update the changed elements
       To regenerate md5sums: 
         checkout md5sums.txt
         cleartool catcr -ele -s {slowTarget} | sed '1,3d;s/\\/\//g;s/@@.*//;s/^.//;' | xargs -i md5sum {} > md5sums.txt
         checkin md5sums.txt
```